# UML relationship between classes..query

Tags: c#, uml

i have a GUI class and it uses lots of other classes by creating objects to those classes. I am not inheriting anything. I just create objects to various classes from other assemblies and use the methods and properties from those classes. In UML i drew all the class block diagrams. Now how to connect all those classes with the Main GUI rendering class? Is this composition ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is a has-a relation. The GUI aggregates those classes.

So either aggregation or composition (later one is stronger).

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

hth

Mario

Answer (score 0):

If the GUI is composed of other classes then its composition.

Comment: I would favor aggregation. The classes do come from other assemblies so I would say the relation is more loose.

Comment: If they are GUI components and can only be contained by some GUI then its composition, but if they can be contained by some other classes too then its aggregation. From his question, it seems he is talking about GUI components, but if not then yes it is aggregation

Comment: yeah, you are right. class A { TextBox tb = new TextBox(); } is clearly a composition.